# How to redirect after redux action

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, typesafe-actions

I'm wondering what the best way of redirecting is after my action has been handled. A user should be redirected to `'/login'` after my action has been fired.

I'm using the [typesafe-actions](https://github.com/piotrwitek/typesafe-actions) library with the following code

**Action**

```
export const Logout = createStandardAction(
  AuthActionTypes.Logout
)<AuthStatus>()
```

**Reducer**

```
case getType(actions.Logout):
  return {
    ...state,
    verifyingTokenStatus: ProgressStatus.Uninitialized,
    tokenRefreshStatus: ProgressStatus.Uninitialized,
    authStatus: action.payload,
    tokenStatus: TokenStatus.Uninitialized,
    user: undefined,
    token: undefined,
  }
```

**Passing the action to my component**

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => ({
  logout: (authStatus: AuthStatus) => dispatch(Logout(authStatus))
})

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(({ children, authStatus, user, logout }: Layout & Props<Component>) => (
  <Layout className="layout" style={{ minHeight: '100vh' }}>
      <AuthTopMenu theme={'light'} mode={'horizontal'} user={user} logout={logout} />
  </Layout>
))
```

**AuthTopMenu has an avatar component that gets the logout action**

```
const removeToken = ({ logout }: AvatarContentProps) => {
  const cookies = new Cookies();
  if (cookies.get('token')) {
    cookies.remove('token')
    logout(AuthStatus.isNotLoggedIn)
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

const AvatarContent = (logout: AvatarContentProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p style={{ margin: 0 }} onClick={() => removeToken(logout)} >
        <Icon type="logout" />
        Logout
    </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm not sure what the best way of handling the redirect is after my action has been fired. I saw that `componentDidUpdate` can be used for checking if my state of the logged in user has been changed but was wondering if my action can take care of this instead?

Comment: You probably need to start looking into [making side effects](https://redux.js.org/faq/actions#how-can-i-represent-side-effects-such-as-ajax-calls-why-do-we-need-things-like-action-creators-thunks-and-middleware-to-do-async-behavior) for your actions

Answer (score 0):

In order to redirect/re-route you need to make use of react-router-dom's `{ withRouter }` component, which will then give your component access to the `props.history`. You need this to redirect from one route to the next

In your AvatarContent:

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom"

const AvatarContent = withRouter((logout: AvatarContentProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
         // pass in history to callBack function
          <p style={{ margin: 0 }} onClick={() => removeToken(logout, props.history)} >
            <Icon type="logout" />
            Logout
        </p>
        </div>
      );
    })

   //give an additional argument to this function so it can take in history
    const removeToken = ({ logout }: AvatarContentProps, history) => {
      const cookies = new Cookies();
      if (cookies.get('token')) {
        cookies.remove('token')
        logout(AuthStatus.isNotLoggedIn)
        //make use of history object
        history.push("/login")
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }
```

Comment: I assume I would have to make my current functional component to a class component in order to achieve this or maybe move this lifecycle method to the root component?

Comment: You would have to turn your functional component into a class-component yes. ORRR you could integrate redux-thunk into your application, which I think is really the smarter decision, if you don't mind having some additional middleware :)

Comment: Redux thunk is already in my application, not sure what redux thunk can do in order to keep this a functional component, you  maybe have an example?

Comment: @Dax, any luck on resolving your question?